# How do I export a group of photos from Shotwell to a folder?

Tags: shotwell

I wish to select photos from the default event directories, and move them into a custom event directory like shown in [this tutorial](http://www.linuceum.com/Desktop/Shotwell.php). Then I want to export the group of photos to a specific folder or USB stick. How do I do this?

Or to the same ends, how can I export a tagged group of photos to a target directory?

Comment: Your basic question here is 'How do I export photos from Shotwell', right? Selecting one or more files and specifying a target directory are easy enough, and Shotwell's FAQ already [covers this](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/share-export.html). Am I missing something? I must be because your question, link to redundant info in a blog post, and answer all seem needlessly complex. Can you help me understand your goal here any better?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Actually, maybe. I am new to Ubuntu and the way the photo managers work here is different from how they work in windows. So I was completely disoriented. I did some searching and came up with nothing and so asked a question here prior to this one and did not get a response. So I did more searching and found what I was looking for, and decided to post it here in the answer to help anyone else who may stumble on this issue. Perhaps the web will suffer the redundancy.

Comment: It's no problem, I was worried I was missing something. Asking and answering your own question [is encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Your question can probably use some editing to make it clearer, which benefits people who find it later. I'll try and you can undo the edits if they are wrong.

Comment: It is much better that way.

Comment: @TomBrossman everything is 'easy enough' once you know how. It never occurred to me to try and select photos in Shotwell even after using it for some time so I presumed it was just a simple program to import photos to the hard drive, and didn't have any customizable export functionality. Again, only found out recently that you can edit photos by double clicking on them. Both of these functions are invisible in the interface and are 'easy enough' once you've discovered them, but they are highly undiscoverable in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are numerous ways to export a group of pictures selected in Shotwell.

The file pane at the left hand side of the application window is a virtual library  with a directory structure and folder names that do not map directly to the system's file directories. This can throw you off if you're coming from windows because the photo managers I've used there display a file directory identical to the system file directory, so you can drag and drop pictures to move the files around.

With Shotwell it's a bit more involved; Here's how to do it:

First create the group of pictures you wish to move about your file system -- here is a short, screenshot-laden tutorial for two ways of doing that: http://www.linuceum.com/Desktop/Shotwell.php -- but to make things flow, I'll add a method not mentioned in the linked tutorial: flags.

Navigate through your Shotwell directories, and flag the photos you want to include in the group of pictures you wish to move. Do this by right clicking the thumbnail, and selecting 'flag' from the right-click menu.

In the file pane towards the top you will see a directory named "flagged." Click on that directory, and all the photos you've flagged will display in the viewing pane. Select all the photos--control A--and click on the 'file' menu at the top of left of the screen. Select Export...and a dialog will pop up, which ends with the file manager's file choosing screen, where you can choose or create the directory to where you wish to move the selected photos. That's it.

I should note that you aren't actually moving the photos. You are but creating copies of them.

Answer (score 7):

1. Select one or more photos.
2. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to export, [from the FAQ](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/share-export.html).
3. Select a target directory.

Comment: @cripton your edit is incorrect, the word 'Shift' does not even appear on the linked FAQ page.

Comment: @cripton actually, You were right. The documentation (and my answer) were wrong. I'll file that as a bug with Shotwell and re-do your edit. Sorry about that and thanks for making the correction.

Comment: This is the correct answer! Thank you so much!